# FireBase Storage getDownloadUrl() .Getting error in continueWithTask method

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

## Error: non-static method continueWithTask(Continuation>) cannot be referenced from a static context where TContinuationResult,TResult are type-variables:

** This the code where error is with continueWithTask**

```
private void StoreProductInformation()
{

    loadingBar.setTitle("Add New Product");
    loadingBar.setMessage("Dear Admin,Please wait....., while we are adding the new Product");
    loadingBar.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    loadingBar.show();

    Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();

    SimpleDateFormat CurrentDate=new SimpleDateFormat("MM DD,YYYY");
    SaveCurrentDate=CurrentDate.format(calendar.getTime());

    SimpleDateFormat CurrentTime=new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss a");
    SaveCurrentTime=CurrentTime.format(calendar.getTime());

    ProductRsndomKey=SaveCurrentDate + SaveCurrentTime;

    final StorageReference filePath = ProdductImageRef.child(ImageUri.getLastPathSegment() + ProductRsndomKey + ".jpg");

    final UploadTask uploadTask=filePath.putFile(ImageUri);

    uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e)
        {
            String message=e.toString();
            Toast.makeText(AdminAddNewProductActivity.this,"Error: "+message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            loadingBar.dismiss();
        }
    }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot)
        {
            Toast.makeText(AdminAddNewProductActivity.this,"Image uploaded successfully... ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Task<Uri> uriTask = UploadTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
                @Override
                public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception
                {
                    if(!task.isSuccessful())
                    {
                        throw task.getException();
                    }
                    downloadImageUrl=filePath.getDownloadUrl().toString();
                    return filePath.getDownloadUrl();
                }
            }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful())
                    {
                        downloadImageUrl=task.getResult().toString();

                        Toast.makeText(AdminAddNewProductActivity.this,"got the Product image , save to Database Successfully...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        SaveProductInfoToDatabase();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });

}
```

## my whole Code

```
package com.example.ecommerce;


import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Continuation;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class AdminAddNewProductActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private String CategoryName , Description,Price,Pname,SaveCurrentDate,SaveCurrentTime;
private ImageView InputProductImage;
private Button AddNewProductButton;
private EditText InputProductName,InputProductDescription,InputProductPrice;
private static final int GalleryPick=1;
private Uri ImageUri;
private String ProductRsndomKey , downloadImageUrl;
private StorageReference ProdductImageRef;
private DatabaseReference ProductsRef;
private ProgressDialog loadingBar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_admin_add_new_product);

    CategoryName=getIntent().getExtras().get("category").toString();
    ProdductImageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("Product Images");
    ProductsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Products");

    AddNewProductButton=findViewById(R.id.add_new_product);
    InputProductImage=findViewById(R.id.select_products_image);
    InputProductName=findViewById(R.id.product_name);
    InputProductDescription=findViewById(R.id.product_description);
    InputProductPrice=findViewById(R.id.product_price);
    loadingBar=new ProgressDialog(this);

    InputProductImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            OpenGallary();
        }
    });
    AddNewProductButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
           ValidateProductData();
        }
    });
}

private void ValidateProductData()
{
    Description=InputProductDescription.getText().toString();
    Price=InputProductPrice.getText().toString();
    Pname=InputProductName.getText().toString();
    if(ImageUri == null)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Product Image is required...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else if(TextUtils.isEmpty(Description))
    {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Please write product description...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else if(TextUtils.isEmpty(Price))
    {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Please write product Price...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else if(TextUtils.isEmpty(Pname))
    {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Please write product Name...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else
    {
        StoreProductInformation();
    }
}

private void StoreProductInformation()
{

    loadingBar.setTitle("Add New Product");
    loadingBar.setMessage("Dear Admin,Please wait....., while we are adding the new Product");
    loadingBar.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    loadingBar.show();

    Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();

    SimpleDateFormat CurrentDate=new SimpleDateFormat("MM DD,YYYY");
    SaveCurrentDate=CurrentDate.format(calendar.getTime());

    SimpleDateFormat CurrentTime=new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss a");
    SaveCurrentTime=CurrentTime.format(calendar.getTime());

    ProductRsndomKey=SaveCurrentDate + SaveCurrentTime;

    final StorageReference filePath = ProdductImageRef.child(ImageUri.getLastPathSegment() + ProductRsndomKey + ".jpg");

    final UploadTask uploadTask=filePath.putFile(ImageUri);

    uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e)
        {
            String message=e.toString();
            Toast.makeText(AdminAddNewProductActivity.this,"Error: "+message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            loadingBar.dismiss();
        }
    }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot)
        {
            Toast.makeText(AdminAddNewProductActivity.this,"Image uploaded successfully... ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Task<Uri> uriTask = UploadTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
                @Override
                public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception
                {
                    if(!task.isSuccessful())
                    {
                        throw task.getException();
                    }
                    downloadImageUrl=filePath.getDownloadUrl().toString();
                    return filePath.getDownloadUrl();
                }
            }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful())
                    {
                        downloadImageUrl=task.getResult().toString();

                        Toast.makeText(AdminAddNewProductActivity.this,"got the Product image , save to Database Successfully...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        SaveProductInfoToDatabase();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });

}

private void SaveProductInfoToDatabase()
{
    HashMap<String,Object> productMap=new HashMap<>();
    productMap.put("pid",ProductRsndomKey);
    productMap.put("date",SaveCurrentDate);
    productMap.put("time",SaveCurrentTime);
    productMap.put("discription",Description);
    productMap.put("image",downloadImageUrl);
    productMap.put("category",CategoryName);
    productMap.put("price",Price);
    productMap.put("pname",Pname);

    ProductsRef.child(ProductRsndomKey).updateChildren(productMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task)
        {
            if ((task.isSuccessful()))
            {
                Intent intent=new Intent(AdminAddNewProductActivity.this,AdminCategoryActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                loadingBar.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(AdminAddNewProductActivity.this,"Product is added Successfully...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else
            {
                loadingBar.dismiss();
                String messg=task.getException().toString();
                Toast.makeText(AdminAddNewProductActivity.this,"Error :"+messg,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }
    });
}

private void OpenGallary()
{
    Intent galleryIntent=new Intent();
    galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(galleryIntent,GalleryPick);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == GalleryPick && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null)
    {
        ImageUri=data.getData();
        InputProductImage.setImageURI(ImageUri);

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please edit your question to provide more details (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask ). What are you trying to achieve? What have you tried? What exactly causes the program to fail and where? Without all this important information we cannot provide you with an answer.

Comment: okk sir , i will remember all these points from next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`continueWithTask` is an instance method not a static method, therefore you need to use the instance variable `uploadTask` to call `continueWithTask`:

```
final UploadTask uploadTask=filePath.putFile(ImageUri);

Task<Uri> uriTask = uploadTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
                @Override
                public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception
                {
                    if(!task.isSuccessful())
                    {
                        throw task.getException();
                    }
                    downloadImageUrl=filePath.getDownloadUrl().toString();
                    return filePath.getDownloadUrl();
                }
            }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful())
                    {
                        downloadImageUrl=task.getResult().toString();

                        Toast.makeText(AdminAddNewProductActivity.this,"got the Product image , save to Database Successfully...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        SaveProductInfoToDatabase();
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: got it .Thanks for the help!!